# How to code highlight words in plural

Tags: discussion, code-formatting, backtick

The backtick is used on many sites of Stack Exchange to format inline text as code.

How do I pluralise words when they refer to code? Let's say I have some item in my code called "ToolBarButton". Which way of doing it is best practice? I have come across the following two:

1. `ToolBarButton`s - seems like the "right" way to do it, but looks ugly and decreases readability.
2. `ToolBarButtons` - easier to read, but it suggests that an element exists which is called exactly "ToolBarButtons", which is simply not true.
3. ToolBarButtons - not formatted at all. But then the camel case looks weird if it's not marked as code.

Sample:

> I have 10 `ToolBarButton`s on my `Form` and I had like to be able to iterate over them all at once without the need to call `Find` on the `Form`. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, you still don't have to use backticks around this all thing, as it's not really code. You can write "All the buttons of type `ToolBarButton`".

Comment: I added a sample for you as I regularly see it on Stack Overflow. Feel free to revert if you don't like it.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I find it difficult to justify the convoluted way of using an objects plural every time I talk about it

Comment: While its not a technical answer (and the exact term is likely to be corrected) I'd go I have 10 *instances of* `ToolBarButton`

Comment: Since it is a name of a type I would maybe go: I have 10 "ToolBarButton"s ... because it's also not really code but I guess there are many ways and opinions how to do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is no right or wrong here. For me, all options have their pros and cons and I really don't know which one is better than the other.

Personally I prefer "`ToolbarButton`s", to stay with your sample.

You want to make clear it is a class name (so code formatting is fine here in my opinion). "`ToolBarButtons`" is wrong here since it is technically incorrect. "ToolBarButtons" will be confusing at times since it might be unclear if it is a word or a mini-code snippet (like in "`apple`s" vs. "apples").

The formatting just looks ugly, that's all. If that is the only problem, maybe the SE team can work on that.

Comment: I sometimes use "`foo` instances" where appropriate to dodge the formatting issues, but have the same preference when that doesn't work